# Using sysfs as replacement for /dev on embedded device

Tags: embedded-linux, sysfs

Until now the books devoted to embedded Linux describe the use of /dev nodes to communicate with the device from userspace. I see however more and more devices which communicate with the driver via sysfs. I could not find any clear explanations how to do this. Does this work in the same was via read / write fops ?

Any tutorials/explanations ? I own Linux device drivers 3rd edition, which only describes the /dev interface for interacting with the driver and /sysfs to display expose some info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I overlooked it: sysfs.txt in the kernel docs explains quite a lot.